# iOS: Show login viewcontroller or "another" viewcontroller inside of UITabbarController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a tabbar with 5 tabs. 
3 of these tabs requires authentication by having an account.
I know one solution is to present a modal viewcontroller when pressing one of these tabs. 
 
I wish to present the login viewcontroller inside of the tabs instead of showing it modally. How can this be done and how can I "reload" the tabbar with the other viewcontrollers once a user has logged in?

Comment: How about adding a UIView as a subview of the first controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating a subclass of UINavigationController which receives a UIViewController to show if user is logged in, and shows the login page in the other case.

```
class CustomNavController:UINavigationViewController {
  let loggedInViewController:UIViewController
  init(loggedInVC:UIViewController) {
    loggedInViewController = loggedInVC
    if (userLoggedIn) {
      onLogin()
    } else {
      onLogout()
    }
    //setup listeners for authentication
    super.init()
  }
  onLogout () {
    self.viewControllers = [AuthenticationVC()]
  }
  onLogin () {
    self.viewControllers = [loggedInViewController]
  }
}


//code for setting up your UITabBarViewController
class MyTabbar:UITabBarViewController {
  init() {
    viewControllers = [
      FirstVC(), 
      SecondVC(),
      CustomNavController(ThirdVC()), 
      CustomNavController(ForthVC()), 
      CustomNavController(FifthVC())
    ]
  }
}
```